# Pass parameters with React Router

Tags: reactjs

Im new to React and i have the following app: (`index.js`)

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Component} from 'react';
import './style.css'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";


import Header from './components/Header'
import Body from './components/Body'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="layout">
              <Header />
              <Body />
              <Footer />
            </div>
          );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Each time I'm going to `localhost:port` Im redirected to this componenet,
I wanted to use Router and extract the data, for example:

`localhost:port/instanceName=value` will route me to same compontents with props `value` only if `value` is `x` or `y`, is that possible?

Comment: Im not sure if I understood the question, but you can use [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) to extract the URL parameters, then render the proper component based on them.

Comment: Are you talking about *query* (`?foo=bar`) or *path* (`/bar`) parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to setup it this way. It is just a custom hook which extract all url parameters.

```
// use-query-string.js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export const useQueryString = () => {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
};
```

Then you can call this in your component which gives you a list of query strings in the url. In fact every time you call it, it would give you a list of passed parameters.

```
const queryString = useQueryString();
```

And finally you can extract what you want. Simply by passing the name of the parameter you are looking for.

```
queryString.get('instanceName')
```

In your case it could be something like this.

```
import { useQueryString } from 'use-query-string';
class App extends Component {
   
   const queryString = useQueryString();

   useEffect(() => {
     const value = queryString.get('instanceName');
     
     if (value === 'x') {
       // do this
     } else if (value === 'y') {
       // do that
     }
     
   }, [queryString])

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="layout">
              <Header />
              <Body />
              <Footer />
            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that your url should be like `localhost:port?instanceName=value`. Actually instead of `/` at the end you need to put `?`. I am not sure if it works with `/` as well. You can test and tweak if it does not.